# Python socket error while using HTTP

Tags: python, http

I am trying to write a simple code shown below in the image

[image]

and i get the below error

[image]

Could you please let me know why i am getting the error and a way to rectify it?

Comment: Please post code as _properly formatted text_. Also, this request is indeed invalid, please read the specs. This isn't a socket error BTW, rather an HTTP one, so the title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTTP request is wrong in a few ways:

1. These should be `\r\n`, not `/n/n`. `\r` and `\n` are escape sequences for a carriage return and a newline so you can write them in a string literal.

   ```
   GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0/n/n
                                                    ^^^^
   ```
2. Sending `GET http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt` is like opening the following link in your browser:

   ```
   http://www.py4inf.com/http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt
   ```

   You want to instead send `GET /code/romeo.txt`
3. You're missing a `Host` header, so the webserver most likely won't respond because a single server may host multiple websites.
4. You need to terminate your HTTP request with a `\r\n`.

A correct request would look like:

```
mysock.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n')
mysock.send('Host: www.py4inf.com\r\n')
mysock.send('\r\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...the above changes made it work. But i have a question, i have already connected my socket to 'www.py4inf.com' then again i need to give the Host name?

Comment: @akashrai: `www.py4inf.com` resolves to `74.208.236.248`. The webserver at that IP address can host hundreds of websites, so just connecting to the server and sending `GET /` is ambiguous, as you never specified *which* website you want to send a request to.